# rqt_plot value vs other value instead of timestamp

Tags: rqt, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to have `rqt_plot` to have just a static plot based on `vector` of values. So instead of having the timestamp on the x axis, could it have some other value.

For example, if you wanted to plot the `position.x` vs `position.y` in an array of `geometry_msgs/Pose`

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257828/rqt_plot-value-vs-other-value-instead-of-timestamp/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't with `rqt_plot`. But you can with [rqt_multiplot](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rqt_multiplot_plugin). It's far superior to rqt_plot with many great features.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-03-24**:
That's cool, I'm going to try it out now. I didn't know about this new package.